# How to create a file with 777 permission?

Tags: unix

In the following script, how can I add `chmod 777` so that file can be created with 777 permission?

```
file="New_file.txt";cd \abc\efg\;  if [ ! -f $file ] ; then touch $file;  fi;
```

Comment: Are you really using `cd \abc\efg\`? Also, does the chmod 777 have to apply if the file already existed?

Comment: I have to create the file if not existed in the folder which has all permissions! But That happens only once! Anyways I have solved my Problem! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks quite obvious:

```
file="New_file.txt"
cd "your_dir"
if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
   touch "$file"
   chmod 777 "$file"
fi
```

Note you should quote variables and also in `cd`, so that you don't have to escape. It also prevents unexpected behaviours if the file name contain spaces, new lines...

One liner:

```
file="new"; cd "your_dir"; if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then touch "$file"; chmod 777 "$file"; fi
```

Comment: you need to modify cd "abc efg", its missing "/"

Comment: Thanks... but `cd \abc\efg\ ` is not a valid expression.

Comment: cd \abc\efg\ is the file path

Comment: It's going to ignore your '\' though and you will end up something like abcefg directory if that exists from your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
file="New_file.txt"; cd /abc/efg/; if [ ! -f $file ] ; then touch $file;  chmod 777 $file; fi
```